# Filter the collection from has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to return a `teacher` object with its collection of `.students`, but *only* the students that meet a criteria. Here is the teacher with its students:

```rb
Teacher.find_by(name: "John Smith").students
# shows all students for teacher john smith
```

Now I try to filter the students so that we produce the same `Teacher` object but with *only* those students aged 20 or older. I thought this would work:

```rb
Teacher.find_by(name: "John Smith").where('students.age > ?', 20)

NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<Teacher:0x00007fae78d292f8>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
Teacher.find_by(name: "John Smith").students.where('students.age > ?', 20)
```

where returns ActiveRecord::Relation
find_by implementation:

```
def find_by
  where(*args).take
end
```

As you can see find_by is the same as where but it returns only one record. This method should be used for getting 1 record and where should be used for getting all records with some conditions.

Comment: I just realised `Teacher.find_by(name: "John Smith").students.where('students.age > ?', 20)` doesn't return the teacher *with* the students, but it instead returns *just the students*. Do you know how to return the teacher with the (filtered collection of) students?

Comment: Sorry I think what I'm after is impossible, so I simply use two lines of code. :)

Comment: ok. just for reference i think you are looking something like [this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-filtered-data-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 1):

You could filter on the `has_many` like this.

```rb
has_many :older_students, -> { where('students.age > ?', 20) }

# Then use it
@students = Teacher.find_by_name('John Smith').older_students
```

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling I realise it's not possible to return an object exactly the same as `Teacher.find_by(name: "John Smith")` but with only the students whose age is > 20 since that would be querying across 2 separate tables.

The simple thing I did instead was

```rb
@teacher = Teacher.find_by(name: "John Smith")

# then 
@students = @teacher.students.where('students.age > ?', 20)
```

i.e. just split it into two lines of code and it will work